# how to force not self closing tag DOMdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

How to generate Empty not self closing tag .

In fact, I need :

```
<IDX></IDX>
```

And some other tags with self closing tab ( so, `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` doesn't work)

I try this :

```
$dom->createElement('IDX', '');
```

But, it's doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem I try to edit nodevalue directly :

```
$idx = $dom->createElement('IDX');
$idx->nodeValue = '';
```

And It's work .